# Setting pins of RS232 using SerialPort .NET without overhead

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, obd-ii

I want to set DTS and RTS pins to true/false in .NET using SerialPort-Class.

When setting pins to true/false and sniffing COM-Port there are alot of other things send to the COM-Port that I don't want.

Sniff-Log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KU7P.png

Code:

```
SerialPort serialPort = portSelector.SelectedPort;
serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10;
serialPort.WriteTimeout = 10;
serialPort.BaudRate = 5;
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

serialPort.Open();
serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
serialPort.DtrEnable = false;
```

If I do the same thing in C it works and is not sending any garbage I don't want. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: The question is not about [tag:COM], I removed the tag. [tag:serial-port] is what you need.

Comment: A bit hard to guess what "down" and "up" could mean in that trace.  Or why you think it is a problem.  But you'll probably feel better if you set the DtrEnable property *before* you call Open().

Comment: I want to do a hardware handshake which requires to send multiple DtrEnable RtsEnable to true/false one directly after another.

Comment: Ended up using unmanaged code importing native DLL functions. http://www.pinvoke.net/